# How do I await in Javascript jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to access mongodb from a Javascript jupyter notebook.

Trying this:

```
// It won't let me import, because it's not a module
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

async function aaa() {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
    const db = client.db('test');
    const collection = db.collection('test');
    const result = await collection.aggregate(agg).toArray();
    console.log(result);
    console.log("DOne")
    client.close();
}

// Can't 'await' here, see below
aaa();
```

Result:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Can't add `await` to function call, because

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

Strictly speaking, this isn't a mongodb-related question and I could have stripped all mongo calls, except, maybe there is a mongodb package that works with javascript? All I need is to access mongodb, I don't care how.